# Dynamically get an instance of a service in controller by some value

Tags: symfony, service

I want to get a service instance in controller (symfony 4) just by value that might look like this:
`$provider = 'youtube'`

That's my setup:

```
Class videoProvider {
//Here I have all common methods for all services
}

Class YoutubeService extends videoProvider {}

Class OtherVideoService extends videoProvider {}
```

Now the  question is how to do something like this. If `$provider = 'youtube'`
Then use YouTube service `new YoutubeService ()` and go on. But what if service does not exist? What then?

Is that even possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not inject all services into some kind of factory?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

- Create a folder with the name Provider
- Create an interface, for example, `VideoProviderInterface`, and put into the folder
- To your interface add the method `getProviderName(): string`
- Create your providers and put them into the folder and implement the interface
- To your services.yaml add the `_instanceof:` option, and add to your interface some tag
- Exclude your provider folders from the `App\:` option in the services.yaml
- Create class, `ProviderManager` and inject your service locator

More information you can find [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html#indexing-the-collection-of-services)

services.yaml

```
_instanceof:
    App\Provider\VideoProviderInterface:
        tags: ['app.provider']

App\Provider\:
    resource: '../../src/Provider/*'

App\Provider\ProviderManager:
    arguments:
        - !tagged_locator { tag: 'app.provider', default_index_method: 'getProviderName' }

App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php,Provider}'
```

VideoProviderInterface

```
<?php

namespace App\Provider;

interface VideoProviderInterface
{
    public function getProviderName(): string
}
```

ProviderManager

```
<?php

namespace App\Provider;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator;

class ProviderManager
{
    /**
     * @var ServiceLocator
     */
    private $serviceLocator;

    public function __construct(ServiceLocator $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function findByName(string $name): ?VideoProviderInterface
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator->has($name) ? $this->serviceLocator->get($name) : null;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this->container->has('my-service-name')` and `$this->container->get('my-service-name')` in a controller is probably what you are looking for. The my-service-name is the name you give the service in your service config and make sure your service is public.

Exemple config ([see doc here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#explicitly-configuring-services-and-arguments))

```
# this is the service's name
site_video_provider.youtube:
    public: true
    class: App\Provider\YoutubeService
    [...]
```

Then in a controller, or any container aware classes: ([see doc here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#public-versus-private-services))

```
$service_name = 'site_video_provider.'.$provider;
if($this->container->has($service_name)){
   $service = $this->container->get($service_name);
}
```